# How to get data from views.py

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

There is one table called Option, and in order to save the value of Option 1, Option 2, views designated Option 2 and saved it to the table. What should I do to retrieve this saved data? There is one table called option, and it is difficult to recall because option 2 is not a table name. How can I solve this problem?

**views.py**

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = OptionForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        option2 = Option()
        option2.name = form.cleaned_data['second_option']
        option2.product_code = product
        option2.save()
```

I wrote it in this way and received it from the view.

```
                       {% for option in option_object %}
                     {% if option.option_code.option_code == value.option_code %}
                         {% if option.product_code == product %}
                     <select type="text" class="form-control" id="optionSelect">
                          <option value="none">옵션을 선택하세요.</option>
                             <optgroup label="{{option.name}}">
                          {% endif %}
```

Here, I want to receive the value of option 2 stored in the option table.

Comment: Please add more details for more help. Now I can just say, you can browse stored data in `python manage.py dbshell` or `Option.objects.get(name=form.cleaned_data['second_option'])` in the python code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try!

1. If you need to get data from an "Option" instance in the template:

Make it available for the template context as usual:

```py
...
return render(
    request, 
    "templates/your_temoplate.html", 
    {
        "option": option2
    })
```

And then using it in the template as usual:

```py
{{ option.name}}
```

2. If you need all the options, first make queryset, like

```py
options = Option.objects.all() # or .filter() with relevant filters
return render(
    request, 
    "templates/your_temoplate.html", 
    {
        "options": options
    }
)
```

And the template for in loop:

```py
{% for option in options %}
   {{ option.name }}
{% endfor %}
```